# HOw can i retrieve name value of input type at run time

Tags: javascript

In my form  I have written something like:

```html
Enter your Name : <input type="text" name="myname" />
<div id="mynameerror"> </div>
<br />
```

In the validation: i retrieve the element with id 'mynameerror', and if the input is empty, and i set some error string into innterHTML.

**Question:**

Now, is it possible to construct id name of **div** tag by retrieving '**name**' property of the '**input**' tag ?

something like:

```
<div id="name property" + "error"> </div>
```

Comment: What validation? What are you trying to do exactly? It is impossible to answer since this question lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

`id`s cannot have spaces. Use an underscore or other separator.

Also, it is bad practice to be altering the id of an element at runtime.

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  // Get the input's name
  var name = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')[0].name;

  // Set the id for the div to be "myname_error"
  document.getElementById("mynameerror").setAttribute("id", name + "_error");

  // Verify the element's id was altered by retrieving it.
  console.log(document.getElementById("myname_error"));
}, 1000);
```

```html
Enter your Name :
<input type="text" name="myname" />
<div id="mynameerror"></div>
```

Comment: No, HTML is a markup language not a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
<span id="fname_error"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Check">
```

Script:

```
<script>
function check(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if(!fname){
     document.getElementById("fname_error").innerHTML = "Text Empty!";
    } else {
     document.getElementById("fname_error").innerHTML = "No Error!";
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, is it possible to generate span id = fname_error dynamically?. that is based on name of input tag. If i introduce another input tag with name ='gname', it should create gname_error.?

Comment: You can use addClass & removeClass function of jQuery. That will help. Visit [Add Class Function](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) for more information